# File composition using command line tools (Linux / Mac)

Tags: html, linux, bash, command

I have a file containing some text and some kind of placeHolder, and another file with some other text

Eg:
myText.txt:

```
some text strings plus a {{myPlaceholderText}} and some more text
```

myPlaceholderText.txt:

```
more text here
```

I want to be able to create a 3rd file containing the string:

```
"some text strings plus a more text here and some more text"
```

Is it possible to do that using command line tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sed is the easiest way to do it:

```
$ sed "s/{{myPlaceholderText}}/$(<myPlaceholder.txt)/g" myText.txt
some text strings plus a more text here and some more text
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And bash is the safest common tool besides interpreted languages.

```
#!/bin/bash

R=$(<myPlaceholderText.txt)
while read -r LINE; do
    echo "${LINE//'{{myPlaceholderText}}'/$R}"
done < myText.txt > another_file.txt
```

Output to another_file.txt:

```
some text strings plus a more text here and some more text
```

Another through awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline r < ARGV[1];ARGV[1]=""}{gsub(/{{myPlaceholderText}}/,r)}1' myPlaceholderText.txt myText.txt > another_file.txt
```